# How to get a list of months between two dates in mysql

Tags: mysql, sql

I hve to get the list of months between two dates in mysql.

```
For Example:My Input is

 From date 23-01-2013
 To Date   01-04-2014

Output Should be 

Jan   2013,
Feb   2013,
March 2013,
.
.
.
Jan   2014,
Feb   2014,
Mar   2014,
Apr   2014.
```

Comment: MySQL is for the storage and retrieval of relational data. Why do you want to do this with MySQL?

Comment: I am generating reports based on conditions.. I am using queries to get the result

Comment: Have you got answer ?

Answer (score 22, accepted):

[SQLFiddle demo](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/d41d8/7282)

```
select 
DATE_FORMAT(m1, '%b %Y')

from
(
select 
('2013-01-23' - INTERVAL DAYOFMONTH('2013-01-23')-1 DAY) 
+INTERVAL m MONTH as m1
from
(
select @rownum:=@rownum+1 as m from
(select 1 union select 2 union select 3 union select 4) t1,
(select 1 union select 2 union select 3 union select 4) t2,
(select 1 union select 2 union select 3 union select 4) t3,
(select 1 union select 2 union select 3 union select 4) t4,
(select @rownum:=-1) t0
) d1
) d2 
where m1<='2014-04-01'
order by m1
```

Comment: Your sqlfiddle doesnt work , it says : create script error

Comment: @julestruong On SQLFiddle site you should click "Build Schema" then "Run SQL".

Comment: Here is a working rendition of this: http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/9eecb/112810

Answer (score 7):

this is a practical solution, it's not so 'elegant' if you wanna see it that way, but it works, and you can make it a function and/or a stored procedure, just with a couple of parameters...

first, we need a table with some records, any table.
 we're gonna use this table, just as a row number table. (you'll need as many rows for the same amount of months you wanna display, having a large table is better) >>

```
SELECT CONCAT(table_schema, '.', table_name) as schema_table, table_rows
FROM   information_schema.TABLES
order by 2 desc limit 0,100
```

this will tell you, the top 100 tables with most records on  your instance, i'm using the mysql.help table for this example, by default, this comes with some thousand records, and it's allways there...

```
set @start_date = '2013-01-23';
set @end_date = '2014-04-01';
set @months = -1;

select DATE_FORMAT(date_range,'%M, %Y') AS result_date from (
    select (date_add(@start_date, INTERVAL (@months := @months +1 ) month)) as date_range
    from mysql.help_topic a limit 0,1000) a
where a.date_range between @start_date and last_day(@end_date);
```

explained:

> 1. set date variales
> 2. set month value, for adding months
> 3. select for each row, a date (we add a month and increment the month variable on the same row)
> 4. filter dates that are between range
> 5. output formated dates.

this is the final output>>

```
January, 2013
February, 2013
March, 2013
April, 2013
May, 2013
June, 2013
July, 2013
August, 2013
September, 2013
October, 2013
November, 2013
December, 2013
January, 2014
February, 2014
March, 2014
April, 2014
```

Answer (score 3):

Try this one:

```
select aDate from (
  select @maxDate - interval (a.a+(10*b.a)+(100*c.a)+(1000*d.a)) day aDate from
  (select 0 as a union all select 1 union all select 2 union all select 3
   union all select 4 union all select 5 union all select 6 union all
   select 7 union all select 8 union all select 9) a, /*10 day range*/
  (select 0 as a union all select 1 union all select 2 union all select 3
   union all select 4 union all select 5 union all select 6 union all
   select 7 union all select 8 union all select 9) b, /*100 day range*/
  (select 0 as a union all select 1 union all select 2 union all select 3
   union all select 4 union all select 5 union all select 6 union all
   select 7 union all select 8 union all select 9) c, /*1000 day range*/
  (select 0 as a union all select 1 union all select 2 union all select 3
   union all select 4 union all select 5 union all select 6 union all
   select 7 union all select 8 union all select 9) d, /*10000 day range*/
  (select @minDate := '2001-01-01', @maxDate := '2002-02-02') e
) f
where aDate between @minDate and @maxDate
```

Comment: Gil, you might want to use a construction with a tally table (perhaps created on-the-fly) rahter than a copy-pasted union.

Answer (score 0):

This SQL from the following helped in my MYSQL. You can update the curdate() value as per your need to get the list of dates of any month.
link: (https://www.programmersought.com/article/26156494713/)

```
SELECT DATE_FORMAT(DATE_SUB(last_day(curdate()), INTERVAL xc-1 day), '%Y-%m-%d') as date
FROM ( 
            SELECT @xi:=@xi+1 as xc from 
            (SELECT 1 UNION SELECT 2 UNION SELECT 3 UNION SELECT 4 UNION SELECT 5 UNION SELECT 6) xc1, 
            (SELECT 1 UNION SELECT 2 UNION SELECT 3 UNION SELECT 4 UNION SELECT 5 UNION SELECT 6) xc2,  
            (SELECT @xi:=0) xc0 
) xcxc) x0 where x0.date >= (select date_add(curdate(),interval-day(curdate())+1 day))
```