# How to select last 30 days dates in MySQL?

Tags: mysql, date, select, subquery

Can I list somehow the dates of last 30 days in `MySQL`? Not from a table!

For example I think about like this:

```
SELECT date WHERE date BETWEEN SUBDATE(NOW(), INTERVAL 30 DAY) AND NOW();
```

Is that possible?

Comment: Search is your friend. Look here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2041575/mysql-query-records-between-today-and-last-30-days

Comment: yep, and there use the `FROM <table>` what I don't want to use

Comment: So what are you trying to do if you don't want to search a table?

Comment: Hmm, do you want to select last 30 dates across all tables in the database?

Comment: Not sure that you can list days like this with MySQL. You should create a function do to that : https://stackoverflow.com/questions/510012/get-a-list-of-dates-between-two-dates

Comment: I want to get back only the dates of last 30 days.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

I hacked this together from someone else's code, but it seems to work:

```
SELECT DATE_FORMAT(m1, '%d %b %Y')
FROM (
SELECT SUBDATE( NOW() , INTERVAL 30 DAY) + INTERVAL m DAY AS m1
FROM (
select @rownum:=@rownum+1 as m from
(select 1 union select 2 union select 3 union select 4) t1,
(select 1 union select 2 union select 3 union select 4) t2,
(select 1 union select 2 union select 3 union select 4) t3,
(select 1 union select 2 union select 3 union select 4) t4,
(select @rownum:=-1) t0
) d1
) d2 
WHERE m1 <= now()
ORDER BY m1
```

The original code by [valex](https://stackoverflow.com/users/1554034/valex) is here:

[How to get a list of months between two dates in mysql](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14811568/how-to-get-a-list-of-months-between-two-dates-in-mysql)

Answer (score 0):

You can do this the "explicit" way.  That is, generate a series of numbers and calculate the date:

```
select date(date_sub(now(), interval n.n day) as thedate
from (select 1 as n union all
      select 2 union all
      . . .
      select 30
     ) n
```