# Get a "count" on a database using "where" to set a limit on the date

Tags: mysql, date, range

I have a database in which i have a table to save reports . Each report haves a date (year-month-day) which is set whenever the report got created .

After a lot of tests i got something to work but just not as i would like it to work.

I want to get the quantity of reports that were made on every month from an initial date (year-month-day) to a final date (year-month-day). But i'm not quite sure how to get it done.

**This is the MySQL sentence i'm using right now:**

```
SELECT meses.month id_mes, count(re_fecha) total
       FROM
       (
               SELECT 1 AS MONTH
                  UNION SELECT 2 AS MONTH
                  UNION SELECT 3 AS MONTH
                  UNION SELECT 4 AS MONTH
                  UNION SELECT 5 AS MONTH
                  UNION SELECT 6 AS MONTH
                  UNION SELECT 7 AS MONTH
                  UNION SELECT 8 AS MONTH
                  UNION SELECT 9 AS MONTH
                  UNION SELECT 10 AS MONTH
                  UNION SELECT 11 AS MONTH
                  UNION SELECT 12 AS MONTH

       ) as meses

LEFT JOIN reportes ON month(re_fecha)  = meses.MONTH
WHERE re_fecha BETWEEN '2017-01-01' AND '2017-08-31'
GROUP BY meses.MONTH, monthName(re_fecha)
```

**This is the following result i'm getting with the MySQL sentence:**

```
id_mes  | total
---------------
  04    | 15
  05    | 5 
  06    | 15
  07    | 2
```

**I'm not sure if this helps in any way, but if i don't use the "where re_fechas... " i get a result that is closer to what we look for:**

```
id_mes  | total         
-------------           
01      | 0         
02      | 0         
03      | 0         
04      | 15            
05      | 5
06      | 15
07      | 2
08      | 6
09      | 0
10      | 0
11      | 0
12      | 0
```

**And finally, what i would like to see:**

```
id_mes       | total            
-------------------     
01-2017      | 0            
02-2017      | 0             
03-2017      | 0            
04-2017      | 15
05-2017      | 5
06-2017      | 15
07-2017      | 2
08-2017      | 6
```

I have two problems with how it works now:

1. When i use the sentence "where" the months that have 0 reports on the specified dates, are not shown. If i do not use "where", i get the things almost in the way i want them, but not in the range of dates i want.
2. The other issue i had is i would like to get the year of the month (As shown in the desired code block above).

I hope this is enough information to understand everything, i'm not sure if i could provide the database, but if you think that would help, let me know.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You almost got it.

If you add `OR re_fecha IS NULL` to your `WHERE` clause, then you would got almost what you wanted.

I came up with another solution that can help you:

```
SELECT meses.aMonth aMonth, COUNT(re_fecha) total
FROM (
  -- Listing all months in period
  SELECT DATE_FORMAT(m1, '%m-%Y') aMonth
  FROM (
    -- Range limit: about 21 years
    SELECT
    ('2017-01-01' - INTERVAL DAYOFMONTH('2017-01-01')-1 DAY) +INTERVAL m MONTH as m1
    FROM (
      SELECT @rownum:=@rownum+1 m FROM
      (SELECT 1 UNION SELECT 2 UNION SELECT 3 UNION SELECT 4) t1,
      (SELECT 1 UNION SELECT 2 UNION SELECT 3 UNION SELECT 4) t2,
      (SELECT 1 UNION SELECT 2 UNION SELECT 3 UNION SELECT 4) t3,
      (SELECT 1 UNION SELECT 2 UNION SELECT 3 UNION SELECT 4) t4,
      (SELECT @rownum:=-1) t0 ) d1
    ) d2 
  WHERE m1 <= '2017-08-31'
  ORDER BY m1) meses
LEFT JOIN reportes ON DATE_FORMAT(re_fecha, '%m-%Y') = meses.aMonth
WHERE re_fecha BETWEEN '2017-01-01' AND '2017-08-31'
OR re_fecha IS NULL
GROUP BY meses.aMonth;
```

Test it: http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/d21de6/27

Example output:

```
aMonth    total
01-2017   0
02-2017   0
03-2017   0
04-2017   15
05-2017   5
06-2017   0
07-2017   2
08-2017   0
```

If you wasn't using MySQL, then you could use a `FULL OUTER JOIN` instead of `LEFT JOIN`.

Keep in mind that this solution is limited to 21 years. Try it changing only the initial date to 1970 and see it for yourself.
If needed, add more `(SELECT 1 UNION SELECT 2 UNION SELECT 3 UNION SELECT 4) tn,` to increase the number of months.

References and useful links:

[MySQL monthly Sale of last 12 months including months with no Sale](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27600863/mysql-monthly-sale-of-last-12-months-including-months-with-no-sale)
[How to get a list of months between two dates in mysql](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14811568/how-to-get-a-list-of-months-between-two-dates-in-mysql)
[How to do a FULL OUTER JOIN in MySQL?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4796872/how-to-do-a-full-outer-join-in-mysql)

Comment: @Strawberry even though this is laborious, it's pretty simple if OP don't need variable ranges of months. And while we need an `FULL OUTER JOIN`, we don't have it on MySQL, so we need to emulate it with a `LEFT JOIN`. I updated my answer adding another way to approach this problem.

Comment: Gotcha - my mistake.

Comment: This works perfectly! We tried it and implemented it already and it's running just as we wanted. I appreciate the reply. Thank you guys.

Answer (score 0):

In your query try to change WHERE to AND.