# Get all months between two dates with count from table in MySql

Tags: mysql, datetime, difference

I have written query for get all month between two days with number of members as count but not able to get all month.

```
SET @start_date = '2017-08-31'; 
SET @end_date = '2018-06-26'; 
SELECT COUNT(1) AS Y, DATE_FORMAT(created_date,'%b %y') AS X 
FROM members m 
WHERE 
    created_date >= @start_date AND 
    created_date <= @end_date 
GROUP BY X 
ORDER BY X;
```

Following output I am getting

```
1   Feb 18
1   Mar 18
1   Nov 17
2   Oct 17
```

But expected result will be

```
2 Oct 17
1 Nov 17
0 Dec 17
0 Jan 18
1 Feb 18
1 Mar 18
```

Online Query [LINK](https://paiza.io/projects/BgmO8z6pHazBcbIF1767Pg?language=mysql)

Comment: can you post the data you are querying?

Comment: You do not have data for the missing months, so they are not brought back in the query

Comment: @DjellalMohamedAniss i have mention LINK. you can find post data

Comment: @will go with this url https://stackoverflow.com/q/14811568/2126088. Not necessary missing month data should be available.

Comment: like @Will said, you don't have that data

Answer (score 0):

Please execute the following SQL to get the desired output:
select EXTRACT(YEAR FROM created_date) AS YEAR, EXTRACT(MONTH FROM created_date) AS MONTH, COUNT(1)
from members
GROUP BY YEAR, MONTH

Noticed that you applied sorting as well, kindly do the same as per your need, it will fetch the count with year and month number.

See the following link for more details on extract function:
https://www.w3schools.com/sql/func_mysql_extract.asp

Answer (score -1):

You need a 'control' table for all the months you are trying to include.  This can be done with a "calendar" table, or by including records as "placeholders" for all the months in the "members" table.

There is a better way to accomplish this, but, for an example, here's the idea (using data from your LINK above)

```
    CREATE TABLE members
(
    member_id INT,
    name VARCHAR(100),
    created_date DATE
);

INSERT INTO members (member_id, name, created_date) VALUES (1, 'Anand Jee', '2017/10/10');
INSERT INTO members (member_id, name, created_date) VALUES (2, 'Anil', '2017/11/21');
INSERT INTO members (member_id, name, created_date) VALUES (3, 'Saurav', '2018/2/10');
INSERT INTO members (member_id, name, created_date) VALUES (4, 'Amit', '2018/3/10');
INSERT INTO members (member_id, name, created_date) VALUES (5, 'Nilesh', '2018/7/17');
INSERT INTO members (member_id, name, created_date) VALUES (6, 'Nitesh', '2018/9/19');
INSERT INTO members (member_id, name, created_date) VALUES (7, 'Ajay', '2019/2/21');
INSERT INTO members (member_id, name, created_date) VALUES (8, 'Rahul', '2019/3/30');
INSERT INTO members (member_id, name, created_date) VALUES (9, 'Sumit', '2019/7/17');
INSERT INTO members (member_id, name, created_date) VALUES (10, 'Gautam', '2017/10/21');

INSERT INTO members (member_id, name, created_date) VALUES (-1, 'ZERO', '2017/08/1');
INSERT INTO members (member_id, name, created_date) VALUES (-1, 'ZERO', '2017/09/1');
INSERT INTO members (member_id, name, created_date) VALUES (-1, 'ZERO', '2017/10/1');
INSERT INTO members (member_id, name, created_date) VALUES (-1, 'ZERO', '2017/11/1');
INSERT INTO members (member_id, name, created_date) VALUES (-1, 'ZERO', '2017/12/1');

INSERT INTO members (member_id, name, created_date) VALUES (-1, 'ZERO', '2018/1/1');
INSERT INTO members (member_id, name, created_date) VALUES (-1, 'ZERO', '2018/2/1');
INSERT INTO members (member_id, name, created_date) VALUES (-1, 'ZERO', '2018/3/1');
INSERT INTO members (member_id, name, created_date) VALUES (-1, 'ZERO', '2018/4/1');
INSERT INTO members (member_id, name, created_date) VALUES (-1, 'ZERO', '2018/5/1');
INSERT INTO members (member_id, name, created_date) VALUES (-1, 'ZERO', '2018/6/1');
INSERT INTO members (member_id, name, created_date) VALUES (-1, 'ZERO', '2018/7/1');
INSERT INTO members (member_id, name, created_date) VALUES (-1, 'ZERO', '2018/8/1');
INSERT INTO members (member_id, name, created_date) VALUES (-1, 'ZERO', '2018/9/1');
INSERT INTO members (member_id, name, created_date) VALUES (-1, 'ZERO', '2018/10/1');
INSERT INTO members (member_id, name, created_date) VALUES (-1, 'ZERO', '2018/11/1');
INSERT INTO members (member_id, name, created_date) VALUES (-1, 'ZERO', '2018/12/1');

SET @start_date = '2017-08-31';
SET @end_date = '2018-06-26';
SELECT COUNT(1)-1 AS Y, DATE_FORMAT(created_date,'%b %y') AS X,DATE_FORMAT(created_date,'%y%m') AS Z
FROM members m
WHERE
created_date >= @start_date AND
created_date <= @end_date
GROUP BY X,Z
ORDER BY Z
```